OpenLayers 8.2.0 custom addCoordinateTransforms
I want to apply a localization to my view after I project it to a state plane. I can use proj4 and project to state plane, but when I try to do this manually through addCoordinateTransforms, I just get put at 0,0 it appears. I have logged out everything and not sure what I am missing.  My transformation in both directions are equal and the lat lon appear to be correct positions when I look at converting local to lat lon to fetch tiles. Is there some secret sauce I am missing
proj4.defs("WGS84", "+proj=longlat +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");
proj4.defs("state", WKT);

ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

var myProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    "code": "MY_LOCAL_PROJECTION",
    "units": "meter",
    "extent": null,
    "worldExtent": null,
    "axisOrientation": "enu",
    "global": false,
    "canWrapX": false,
    "defaultTileGrid": null,
    "metersPerUnit": 1
});

ol.proj.addProjection(myProjection);

ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(
    'EPSG:4326',  // From EPSG:4326 (WGS84)
    "MY_LOCAL_PROJECTION",  // To your custom projection
    function (cords) {
        let coords = cords.slice();
        var plane_2_local_matrix = LOCALIZATION_MATRIX ? math.matrix(LOCALIZATION_MATRIX) : LOCALIZATION_MATRIX;

        var localPointsMetric;
        var planeCords;
        let fakeElevation = 0;
        coords.push(fakeElevation)
        planeCords = (proj4("EPSG:4326", "state", coords));
        planeCords.push(1);

        if (plane_2_local_matrix)
            localPointsMetric = (math.multiply(plane_2_local_matrix, planeCords)._data);
        else
            localPointsMetric = (planeCords);

        let CompleteLocal = math.divide(localPointsMetric, unitConversion).slice(0, 2);

        console.log(cords, CompleteLocal)
        return CompleteLocal;
    },
    function (cords) {
        let coords = cords.slice();
        var plane_2_local_matrix = LOCALIZATION_MATRIX ? math.matrix(LOCALIZATION_MATRIX) : LOCALIZATION_MATRIX;
        var unitConversion = (UNIT_DISTANCE == 'Meters' ? 1 : UNIT_DISTANCE == 'Feet' ? 0.3048006096012192 : 0.304800000000002170176)

        let fakeElevation = 0;
        coords.push(fakeElevation)
        coordsMetric = math.multiply(coords, unitConversion);
        coordsMetric.push(1);

        if (plane_2_local_matrix)
            planeCords = math.multiply(math.inv(plane_2_local_matrix), coordsMetric)._data;
        else
            planeCords = points;

        completedLatLon = proj4("state", "EPSG:4326", planeCords).slice(0, 2);

        console.log(cords, completedLatLon)
        return completedLatLon;
    }
);

OPEN_LAYER_MAP = new ol.Map({
    target: 'open_layer_map',  // The id of the div where the map will be displayed
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()  // OpenStreetMap as the base layer
        }),
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'MY_LOCAL_PROJECTION',
        center: ol.proj.transform([- 74.771357, 40.131067], 'EPSG:4326', 'MY_LOCAL_PROJECTION'),
        //ol.proj.transform([-74.747601, 40.149530], 'EPSG:4326', 'state'),
        zoom: 16  // Initial zoom level
    })
});

Results of debugger


OSM is in EPSG:3857, you will also need to add  transforms between that and your view projection (first transform EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326 than apply your transform, for the inverse apply you inverse transform then transform  EPSG:4326  to EPSG:3857)
